# AggregateException on GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()

Tags: c#, firebase, google-oauth

With this code:

```
private async Task<string> DoCustomToken(string arg)
{
    try
    {
        var uid = "some-uid";
        FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault(),//GoogleCredential.FromFile("C:/config-production-firebase.json"),
            ServiceAccountId = "<my-id>@<my-project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com",

        }) ;
        string customToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.CreateCustomTokenAsync(uid);
        return customToken;
    }

    catch (Exception e) { return e.GetType().FullName + " - " + e.Message; }

}
```

I'm getting `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred` at `GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()`

I'm trying to generate a custom token with C# to be used in a DLL.

PS: When I try with `GoogleCredential.FromFile` I get a `InvalidOperationException: Error deserializing JSON credential data`

**Enviroment**

`FirebaseAdmin: 1.9.1`

`Newtonsoft.Json: 12.0.3`

`.NET Framework: 4.8`

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Comment: @Jacob `System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred`

Comment: Have you checked the "InnerExceptions" property of the AggregateException object to see if there is a lower-level issue?

Comment: @MikeMarshall, no, I'll try to do it.

Comment: @MikeMarshall I got a better message of my error. Thanks for this tip. and Sorry, but It's my fist contact with C#. Can you put your comment as answar to accept it ?

Comment: No Problem.  I added the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the `InnerExceptions` property of the `AggregateException` class to find more specific causes of your issue.  `AggregateException` objects are thrown when a `Task`-related exception occurs.